# Font changes when I refresh NextJS application

Tags: next.js

I have a problem with my Button component, whenever I refresh the page, it loses the font class added with "next/fonts".

[classlist before refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/betuv.png)

[classlist after refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8J7Y.png)

**Here's the code for the Button component**

```
import clsx from "clsx";
import { roboto_cond } from "./fonts";

interface ButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Button = ({ className, children, ...rest }: ButtonProps) => {
  return <button {...rest} className={clsx(
    `border border-white rounded px-7 py-3 mt-10 text-lg ${roboto_cond.className} font-light`, className
  )}>{children}</button>;
};
```

**And here's the code for the parent component**

```
export default function TopNav({ friends, getColor }: any) {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="w-full flex justify-start gap-5 p-5">
        {friends?.map((friend: Friend) => (
          <Button
            key={friend.id}
            style={{ backgroundColor: `#${friend.color}` }}
            onClick={() => getColor(friend)}
            className="mt-0"
          >
            <p>{friend.name}</p>
          </Button>
        ))}
        <Link href="/app/add">
          <Button className="mt-0">Add friend</Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

I have tried to change the type of the component from client to server, but didn't work. Worth mentioning, that, the parent component also has a parent component, which is, in fact, a client component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Next 14 issue. However, here is how to stop the font from changing on page refresh:

1. Use the font in your layout.js, then specify the elements from your globals.css file.
2. If the font changes when you click on the button then you need to change the Link to the anchor element `<a>`.